# Auto highlighting in text or numeric box in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am in the beginning level of blazor. I need to know when clicking on the text box or numeric box, the text that is in the text box or numeric box should automatically highlight according to the following figure.

[image]

how can I do that using blazor?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by adding a javascript focus event handler to the element:

```
onfocus="this.select()"
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

**_Host.cshtml**

```
<script>
    function selectText(inputId) {
        var inp = document.querySelector("#" + inputId);
        if (inp.select) {
            inp.select();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Standard</label>
    <input id="@MyID" @bind-value="@MyText" @onclick="@SelectText" />
</div>

@code {
    public string MyText { get; set; } = "text";
    public string MyID { get; set; } = "input-id1";

    async Task SelectText()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("selectText", MyID);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sergio Junior's answer is about 10 characters long and works.  The JS Interop isn't necessary.

Comment: can't we do this without using javascript??

Comment: @Buddhi, it may be possible but I could not find how to do it.  Blazor does not have the full set of control over the DOM like Javascript does, so occasionally you may need to integrate a few lines of JS like I did in this example.

Comment: One thing you can consider is to make an input component that performs the above behavior and use that throughout your code.  This is the Blazor way.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this as the component is rendered rather than onclick?
Ive tried overriding the OnAfterRenderAsync but it doesnt seem to work.